# How to SSH to a linux machine out in the wild

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a linux machine that is portable and so will connect to different routers. The linux machine has a script that will automatically update its current public IP everytime it connects to the Internet.

Now, from my computer I want to `ssh` into this linux machine. Assuming that the linux machine is live and connected to the internet, I ran `ssh -vvvv root@LinuxPublicIP`, but the operation timed out:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 209.133.4.10 [209.133.4.10] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 209.133.4.10 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Help is appreciated

**EDIT**

I'd rather not use a dynDNS and instead have my linux machine constantly update its Public and Internal IP on a database. Let's say that my current public ip is `209.10.12.23` and internal ip is `10.0.20.18`.

How can I ssh?! Running `ssh root@209.10.12.23` would be SSHing into the router, and not my linux machine.

**EDIT**

Is it at all possible to ssh into a device that changes location and connects to different routers, without somebody manually setup the port forward on the new router?

Comment: Can you ping the server?

Comment: @paulsm4, The answer to 1 and 2 are yes. My problem is exactly what you said at the end; this linux machine will be out in the wild, and I have no control over the router it connects to! So I need to SSH into it, irrespective of what router it is connected to, and with no setup on the router whatsoever.

Comment: Because you have a router between your SSH client and your SSH server, you need to make the router forward the SSH traffic to the internal server IP. This is done through your router's configuration and it's usually called "Port Forwarding". Tell it to forward port 22 to the internal IP address of your SSH Server, then try to connect from an external client again.

Comment: There are two obstacles to overcome when connecting externally. 1) The firewall on the network your SSH client is on. If they block port 22, you will have to do your SSH on a different port. There is no getting around that. 2) Your Router that Your SSH server sits behind on Your network. You have to insure, as I mentioned above, that it is properly routing SSH requests to your internal SSH server's IP.

Comment: Unless you have control over the router between your Linux host and the internet ... you're pretty much screwed :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote up above, but wanted to clarify further:

When connecting to an SSH server on your home network from an external IP (Say if you are at Starbucks or something) there are 4 components to be aware of:

1. Your SSH Client, which is the laptop you are working.
2. The network and it's firewall to which your SSH Client/laptop is connected.
3. The router at your house that handles all of the incoming and outgoing traffic from your home network
4. The SSH Server behind you router, in your house.

[image]

You have control over 1, 3, and 4, but you have no control over 2 (Starbuck's network and their firewall). They may be, and probably are, blocking certain ports. SSH uses 22 by default, so things may get a little tricky.

Generally the way to do this is to find a port that is open on the network's firewall. This is why folks are recommending port 80 or 443 or 21, as those are most commonly left open on any network.

On your router, you will have to enable port forwarding for which ever port you want to use. Generally you can choose which port it should look for externally (say Port 443) and which internal IP to route it as well as the port it should route it to. This would be your SSH server's internal IP and Port 22. In your router's config it may look something like:

[image]

If you find an open port and forward it properly on your router, then you can connect your SSH Client to your SSH Server by using your Home's external IP (209.10.12.23) and that port you found (443 for example). From a linux command line it would look like:

```
ssh yourusername@209.10.12.23 -p 443
```

If you are getting a timeout still, it means your client isn't getting through to your server, which could be because your chose a bad port that is blocked, or you have improperly forwarded the port on your router.

Note also, that your external SSH client/laptop does not need to know the internal IP address of the SSH Server, just your public IP of your home network.

Lastly, if you are opening things up so you can connect from an external source, I would highly recommend using a SSH keypair instead of a password for authentication, and also not allowing `root` to connect via SSH on your box. Someone cracking your password would have the ability to completely decimate your server.

Answer (score 1):

The "Public" IP address will have to be routed properly to the server, so when the server moves the IP routing will have to change. This is the reason `dynDNS` or dynamic DNS was created. In a dynDNS setup you will connect to the server via a hostname.

EX:

```
ssh -vvvv user@myhostname.tld
```

The `hostname` is served via the Dynamic DNS server where the IP can be changed at a very low `TTL` (time to live) so you can always access the server. Now you may be asking how the dynDNS server knows your IP address. This is typically achieved via a deamon/service running on the server. When it connects to the internet it then calls the Dynamic DNS server to update the IP is has stored for your hostname, allowing routing to the hostname.

Another method that is used when a service can not be deployed is implementing a `proxy` connection from the server when it connects to the internet. This typically will place the server within a `VLAN` on the proxy and allow you to use local hostnames to connect to it via the proxy. This method is preferred for secure access to the server where a service can not be used due to heightened security requirements, and the server does not publish publicly available resources such as a web server serving HTML.

Comment: Is it at all possible to ssh into a device that changes location and connects to different routers, without somebody manually setup the port forward on the new router?

Comment: Your device running the ssh server moves around behind different routers or different networks?

Comment: The Linux machine is a portable device, and it will physically move to even different cities! My server though is running on AWS, and I want to be able to SSH into my linux machine from the UI dashboard running on the AWS

Answer (score 1):

The router the machine connects to is most likely using NAT. That means you need to forward the SSH port (22 by default) to the machine. You do that in the router's configuration interface.

There is no way around this (no tricks, workarounds, hacks, or whatever) when using NAT. The port forward is needed.

*If* the router in question is running UPnP, then the machine can request a port forward automatically. You can do that using the MiniUPnP tool:

http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/

However, many routers have UPnP disabled due to security concerns. Also, some routers may not allow forwarding port 22, since they use it for themselves. So in your case it's best to configure sshd to use another port.

Answer (score -1):

It is very likely that "out in the wild" includes places which filter incoming traffic. Ports 22, 25, 465, 587, and a few other ports are very commonly filtered. Commonly *unfiltered* ports include 20, 21, 80, 443, and all the ports above 1023.

If you can set up the server to accept SSH on port 21 (commonly used for FTP) or even 80 (commonly used for HTTP) then you *may* see better availability in filtered locations.

When SSH is running on i.e. port 80, you can access it as so:

```
$ ssh -p 80 user@LinuxPublicIP
```

I note that the OP mentions that he logs in as root. Never do that, rather log in as an unprivileged user and then `su` to root or use `sudo`.

Comment: Yes, good idea. So how do I ssh? I'm assuming that the public IP my linux machine updates the database with is the IP of the router. So I need to pass both the Public IP (Router) and the internal IP (machine within that network). Then how do I ssh?

Comment: I would never recommend running SSH on 80, 21 or any "unfiltered" port below 1024 a.ka. the [privileged ports](http://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html).

Comment: @MattSizzle: For a general purppose server I agree with you. But as a stop-gap measure for a laptop that connects to various public networks that the system administrator does not control, running SSH on port 80 is a viable workaround.

Comment: I agree with MattSizzle.  I'd only consider redirecting ssh to port 80 as a *VERY LAST RESORT*, if there were *NO OTHER* alternatives.

Comment: @paulsm4: When port 22 is filtered (as is often the case with public networks), there in fact are no other alternatives.

Comment: Well actually there are ALOT of ports > 1024 that you can use for this purpose. A common unprivileged port for this purpose is `2222`. If you do not have access to control the firewall use a Proxy as I mentioned as you CAN proxy through 443 or 80 on pretty much any network.